# Tab Bar Controller disappearing when moving back to another view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, segue

I want to create an app that lets the user click on a button on V1 on the navigation bar. This will segue to V2  where they can press another button on the navigation bar on V2 and it will bring them back to V1 which has the tab bar controller at the bottom. I don't want the tab bar on V2 and I don't want V2 as a tab bar item. When I try this the tab bar disappears on V1 when I segue back to V1 from V2.

TAB BAR CONTROLLER -> TAB BAR ITEM (V1) -> V2(Via navigation bar button item on V1) ->  back to V1(Via navigation bar button item on V2)

I have added `[self.navigationController, popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to my button function but it comes up with an error - expected expression in container literal.

Apart from this code I have not got any other code in my app yet.

I am using Xcode 8.0 and Swift 3.0

Comment: you mentioned you are using Swift 3.0 but the function you've added is in Obj-c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem after days of trying to figure out an answer. You need to add this to any view controller.

```
@IBAction func unwindToViewController (sender: UIStoryboardSegue){

    }
```

Then you can add a segue from bar button item to the exit icon on the view controller.

[You can view an image of the VC scene here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTv2p.png)

Answer (score 0):

First create subclass of `UITabBarController`, Then add properties to `AppDelegate`

```
var navController: UINavigationController?
var tabController: MyTabController?
```

If you want to show tab bar controller on app launch then put these code in `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
 let myStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) as UIStoryboard
 self.tabController = myStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabController") as? MyTabController
//self.navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.tabController!)
//self.window?.rootViewController = self.navController
 self.window?.rootViewController = self.tabController
 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 return true
```

If you want to jump on tab bar after login or something else then , add property to that controller

```
 var appDelegate: AppDelegate!
```

in `viewDidLoad`

```
 appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
```

And method should like

```
 func logIntoApp() {

    appDelegate.tabController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabController") as? MyTabController
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = appDelegate.tabController
 }
```

Then in your tab item view controller , create property of `AppDelegate` and assign delegate as above.

And methods should be like :

```
@IBAction func showWithTab(_sender: AnyObject) {

      let DefaultVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DefaultViewController") as! DefaultViewController
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DefaultVC, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func showWithoutTab(_sender: AnyObject) {

      let DefaultVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DefaultViewController") as! DefaultViewController

    // You can create your own animation
      UIView.transition(from: (appDelegate.tabController?.view)!, to: (appDelegate.navController?.view)!, duration: 0.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn) { (finished) in

      self.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = self.appDelegate.navController
    }

    // OR you can use like this way
      UIView.transition(from: self.view, to: DefaultVC.view, duration: 0.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn) { (finished) in

      self.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = self.appDelegate.navController
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple Tab Bar?
Something like this:

[image]

and in VC1 :

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    myTab.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: When I go back to the view with the tab bar the tab bar has disappeared.

Comment: When I set a segue to VC2 using the navigation controller and a segue from VC2 back to VC1 using a push segue in the naviagtion controller the bar button item I have added onto the navigation bar on VC2 has disappeared. Sorry if my question doesn't make sense but what I want to do is have two VC linked with a tab bar. Then on one of the VC I want to have a bar button item in the navigation bar which lets to segue to another VC that doesn't have a tab bar implemented. On this VC I have another bar button item in the navigation bar which lets me go back to my VC with a tab bar. Thanks.